# TCL: How to give different output in set out [command] and command?

Tags: tcl

I want to give different output in different invocation of "mycommand". Detailed output (name and age) if "mycommand"  is invoked directly or smaller output (only first col) if used in set command. Is this possible in TCL ?

```
> set output [mycommand]
> puts "$output"
  name1
  name2
  name3
> mycommand
  name1 age29
  name2 age30
  name2 age31
>
```

Comment: really, try to rephrase your question - can't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in to allow that, and doing so would probably cause more problems that it would solve. If you need it to produce different results in different contexts, the best thing is to implement an option to control the output (eg: [mycommand -verbose]`)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* check to see if the global `tcl_interactive` variable is set and true, and use `info level` to see (OK, to guess) if you're being called directly, but it would be a total hack.

```
if {$::tcl_interactive && [info level]==1} {
    # do a verbose thing
} else {
    # do a not-so-verbose thing
}
```

But I advise you not do this. Let the caller ask for one or the other mode explicitly, and pick a sensible default. (Which one? When are you laziest?)